# What is gradle artifact transform task and why it takes so long?

Tags: gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, aar, artifact

I ran the profiler for my build, and under **Artifact Transform** tab, I can see different times taken by the transform tasks.

First I thought that the `1m16.09s` mark was that the process finished 1m after I started the build, and that the rest of 26 minutes time was for compilation efforts. However, if I sum all of the times in the Duration column, they will sum up to exactly 27m21.96s. Thus I understand that each of the transform tasks take the time mentioned at the right.

So I am wondering, do running transforms take that much time? Why would it take 1m to transform a common jar?

[image: Artifact Transoforms]